# How to prepare PATH when embedding Python in C++?

Tags: python, c++, anaconda

I am implementing an interface which allows Python to be loaded and used from a Windows C++ application. It should be able to use any Python registered in the Windows registry. This seems to work fine with e.g. Python 3.8 downloaded from www.python.org. However, with current Anaconda/Python 3.7 I am having problems. It looks like it expects a lot of directories to be present at PATH, and this knowledge seems to be hidden in a cryptic conda.bat file. Especially the folder `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\Library\bin` seems critical, without this e.g. numpy won't load.

In short, assuming that I start just with the following info piece from registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.7\InstallPath]
@="C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3"
```

how should I prepare PATH and potentially other things so that the loaded Python DLL, from Anaconda or not, would be fully functional? For this particular Anaconda version I can add them by hand, but this seems not so sustainable.

I know that one solution is to select a check box during Anaconda install which will put the needed directories to the system PATH. However, this check box is not selected by default and is marked as "not recommended", so there is not much hope that our end users will actually check it.